# Get only first item emitted by Interval

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

I have an observable which subscribe to interval Observable, and I cannot guarantee that service can continue until I emit the first item.

So I create a future to block the operation until emitt first one. Problem is, that since is interval subscriber never unsubscribe if I´m right so the operations never ends. So it´s mean that the future.complete it will be executed for every interval

```
public static Future<Void> initialize(Scheduler scheduler) {
    Future<Void> future = Future.future();
    if (observable == null) {
        observable = getProductsObservable();
        observable.subscribeOn(scheduler);
        observable.subscribe(newProducts -> {
            future.complete();
            products.clear();
            products.addAll(newProducts);
        });
    }
    return future;
}

private static Observable<List<String>> getProductsObservable() {
    return Observable.interval(0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .doOnNext(time -> log.info("New job run at {}", new Date(time)))
            .map(time -> getProducts());
}
```

Maybe interval was not the best choice for a Cron job.

My question it would be, how I could determine if the interval emit the first time. Just to do the future.complete() just one time.

EDIT:

I end up using ReplySubject to share the items between the two observables. But still not convinced, since I need to use first() in order to unsubscribe my subject once that I receive the first item emitted for the other observable.

```
   public static synchronized Single<String> initialize(Scheduler scheduler, ProductClient productClient) {
        if (discountableSubject == null) {
            discountableSubject = ReplaySubject.create(1);
            getProductsObservable(scheduler, productClient)
                    .map(newProducts -> products = newProducts)
                    .map(products -> "done")
                    .subscribe(discountableSubject);
        }
        return getFirstElementAndUnsubscribe(scheduler).toSingle();
    }

    private static Observable<String> getFirstElementAndUnsubscribe(Scheduler scheduler) {
        return discountableSubject.observeOn(scheduler).first();
    }

    private static Observable<List<String>> getProductsObservable(Scheduler scheduler, ProductClient productClient) {
        return Observable.interval(0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS, scheduler)
                .doOnNext(time -> log.info("New job run at {}", new Date(time)))
                .map(time -> getProducts(productClient));
    }
```

If someone has a better option please let me know.

Comment: In which environment are you running? Android/ Web/ ...?

Comment: If you are running with one thread per request, you will not have a cron job, because the request will be returned and the thread exits. Which framework are you using? Netty, Spring on top of Tomcat/ Glashfish?

Comment: Vertx, 1 thread per Verticle. But this Observable using interval is running in a separate thread

Comment: Ok, I will read up on VertX and try to solve your question.